# How can I check for a missing "." at the end of a cell and adding a "." at the end of a cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want to make a macro that checks if a sentence has a "." at the end of the sentence and if not I want to add a "." at the end of a sentence. I want to make a macro to prevent that mistake to make proofreading a bit easier and in an Excel list with a Column where in each row are 1-2 Sentences in 300+ rows human error is bound to happen. I just started Coding as you can tell probably, but it would be a huge help if you could tell me how you would approach this problem. Thank you in advance

I tried to record a Macro with the CONCATENATE function `=CONCATENATE (A1;".")` but that does not check if there already is a "." at the end meaning that if there already is a "." it would just add another one.

Answer (score 3):

Check if last symbol in cell is . and if not, then concatenate. Formula:

```
=IF(RIGHT(A1,1)=".",A1,CONCATENATE(A1,"."))
```

Where `RIGHT(A1,1)` selects 1 most right symbol in cell. And `IF` formula checks if it is equal to "dot" symbol.

[image]

You can also wrap `A1` in `TRIM` formula to avoid this kind of scenario:

[image]

```
=IF(RIGHT(TRIM(A1),1)=".",A1,CONCATENATE(TRIM(A1),"."))
```